# Date for Previous Monday Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Today is 02/27/2013 which is Wensday.
I need formula which will return me date for previous Monday.which would be (02/17/2013)

I need to so I can use for file name or email subject in my vba code which sends emails.

```
With oMail
     'Uncomment the line below to hard code a recipient
     .To = "myemail@email.com"
     'Uncomment the line below to hard code a subject
     .Subject = "Current Report"
     .Attachments.Add WB.FullName
    .Display
End With
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? If you haven't tried anything, then perhaps this will get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227527(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @Sam, your link is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: @DougGlancy is it? It works for me. I couldn't use the built in SO link functionality because the MSDN link contains parenthesis in itself. Did you maybe see it before I made the edit?

Comment: @Sam,that's right. I did.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Public Function LastMonday(pdat As Date) As Date
    LastMonday = DateAdd("ww", -1, pdat - (Weekday(pdat, vbMonday) - 1))
End Function
```

Weekday(yourdate, vbMonday) returns a 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, etc. so

```
pdat - (Weekday(pdat, vbMonday) - 1)
```

Will give us the most recent Monday by subtracting the Weekday()-1 # of days from the passed date.

```
DateAdd("ww", -1, ...)
```

subtracts one week from that date.

```
LastMonday(cdate("2/27/13"))
```

Returns 2/18/2013 (which is Monday, not the 17th)

Comment: Hi, How can I use this ? do I enter `=DateAdd("01/01/2013")` ?

Comment: If you include the function in your VBA module, then you can do something like this:     strSubject = "Today's subject is about last Monday (" & Format(LastMonday(Date), "mm/dd/yyyy") & ")"
    
    With oMail
        .Subject = strSubject
    End With

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the difference between Weekday(Now()) and 2 (= weekday for monday), then add 7.

Comment: Are you sure that will return **previous** Monday - not the next one?

Comment: Peter, I should have been more specific. If you add the difference to 7 and THEN substract that from today, you should end up with the previous Monday!

Comment: edited this answer to include a concrete example (in-cell calculation) after spending a few minutes figuring it out myself.  "=TODAY()-(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)+7)"

Comment: also: =TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)-7  (removed 2 parentheses)

Answer (score 1):

Dan's answer should cover your needs in VBA

or in Excel worksheet formula, you could do something like this:

```
    =TEXT(DateCell- (WEEKDAY(DateCell,2)-1),"dddd mmmm dd")
```

so DateCell is a range containing the date that you want to find the date of the previous Monday!

so if you put 08/04/2012 in DateCell, then that formula will retrun Monday 2nd April!

(credit to MrExcel.com and Google search!)
HTH
Philip

Answer (score 0):

To make the accepted answer's function a bit more versatile, a couple of minor changes lets you specify which day of week, and how far back/forward you want it.

```
Public Function LastDow(pdat As Date, dow as integer, _&
                optional weeksOffset = -1 as integer) As Date
    LastDow = DateAdd("ww", weeksOffset, pdat - (Weekday(pdat, dow) - 1))
End Function
```

With this function you can get, say, the next Wednesday:

```
dim myDt as date
dim nextWed as date
myDt = now()
// Get next Wednesday (dow = Wednesday, weeksOffset is +1
x = LastDow(myDt, vbWednesday, 1)
```

Thanks again to the original solution author (Dan Meltheus).