# Get dates of Mon-Fri of previous week

Tags: vba, excel, date, weekday

I'm trying to implement [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15116929/619177) to get the dates for Monday-Friday of the previous week, testing with this:

```
Public Sub listPreviousWeekDays()

Dim dayCtr As Long

For dayCtr = 2 To 6
    Debug.Print DateAdd("ww", -1, Now - (Weekday(Now, dayCtr) - 1))
Next

End Sub
```

However, this gives:

```
4/10/2017 9:27:18 AM 
4/11/2017 9:27:18 AM 
4/12/2017 9:27:18 AM 
4/6/2017 9:27:18 AM 
4/7/2017 9:27:18 AM
```

My goal is for it to return:

```
4/10/2017 9:27:18 AM 
4/11/2017 9:27:18 AM 
4/12/2017 9:27:18 AM 
4/13/2017 9:27:18 AM 
4/14/2017 9:27:18 AM
```

EDIT: to avoid an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I'll explain what I'm trying to do: I want to run a macro that fills in a block of cells with the previous week's Mon-Fri dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated

As the OP pointed out, the linked code doesn't work for this particular use case when the starting date is a Sunday.  Here's a fix:

```
Option Explicit   ' always always always use this

Public Function MondayLastWeek(pdat As Date) As Date
    Dim weekday_increment As Long
    weekday_increment = weekday(pdat, vbMonday) - 1
    MondayLastWeek = DateAdd("ww", IIf(weekday_increment = 6, 0, -1), pdat - weekday_increment)
    ' IIf: if we're on Sunday, pdat-weekday_increment is already the date we want.
End Function

Public Sub listPreviousWeekDays()
    Dim monday As Date
    monday = MondayLastWeek(Now)

    Dim dayCtr As Long
    For dayCtr = 0 To 4
        Debug.Print monday + dayCtr
    Next
End Sub
```

#### Original answer

This works for me:

```
Public Sub listPreviousWeekDays()

    ' First, get last week's Monday just as in the linked question    
    Dim LastMonday As Date
    LastMonday = DateAdd("ww", -1, Now - (Weekday(Now, vbMonday) - 1))

    ' Then, loop over the rest of the week.
    ' Monday + 0 days => Monday
    ' Monday + 4 days => Friday
    Dim dayCtr As Long
    For dayCtr = 0 To 4
        Debug.Print LastMonday + dayCtr
    Next

End Sub
```

Output:

```
4/10/2017 12:38:17 PM 
4/11/2017 12:38:17 PM 
4/12/2017 12:38:17 PM 
4/13/2017 12:38:17 PM 
4/14/2017 12:38:17 PM
```

I think the issue is that the second parameter to `Weekday` doesn't specify which day you *want*.  Instead, it specifies which day of the week is *weekday number 1* ([some documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/weekday.php)).  Instead of messing with `Weekday`, just get the Monday using the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15116929/2877364), then add days as necessary.

Comment: If I run the linked answer for a Sunday, I get the Monday from 2 weeks prior.  Try `lastMonday("4/16/2017")` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Hello there. I understand this is a fairly old thread but would like to know how to : 1) Put these dates into a range and 2) Apply WorksheetFunction.MIN to get LastMonday and WorksheetFunction.MAX to get LastFriday

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the issue.

```
Public Sub listPreviousWeekDays()

Dim dayCtr As Long
For dayCtr = 2 To 6
Debug.Print DateAdd("ww", -1, Now - (Weekday(Now, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek)) + dayCtr)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the output in Ascending order

Comment: It appears that the OP's code, and your code, are returning Mon-Wed of last week, and Thu and Fri of *the week before that*.  I believe the OP is trying to get dates all in last week, not spread across two weeks.

Comment: @cxw, that is correct.  I want to get the Mon-Fri dates from the previous week.

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan, this has the same problem as cxw's solution: if it is run on a Sunday, it gives the dates from 2 weeks ago instead of last week.  If you substitute `"4/16/2017"` for `Now` you can replicate this problem.