# Change Cell Value after being copied by macro

Tags: vba, excel

Download for Sheet to better understand.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/urncoww8prj6rc1/AccountabilityScorecardDigital.xlsm?dl=0

I am creating a workbook that has auto-creating sheets. Each sheet has the same data with the exception of the dates. I simply need the one cell "A1" to auto-change it's name to the next date range.

```
For Example: Sheet1 Cell A1 "DEC 11-15 2017" 
    Copied : Sheet2 Cell A1 "Dec 18-22 2017"
   Copied2 : Sheet3 Cell A1 "Dec 25-29 2017"
   Copied3 : Sheet4 Cell A1 "Jan 01-05 2017"
```

It has to follow this naming convention so that the rest of the sheet updates accordingly.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Name = Range("A1")`

Comment: @user1274820 this isn't relevant to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: All of the numbers and dates within the cell ? Do you mean all of them within the sheet that has just been copied? is this done on a monthly basis? You can't have a self-changing macro. The code will be as you write it. You can have code that is triggered by events that can use DATE functions (broad category) combined with instructions to make changes.

Comment: I was typing an edit for your second part... anyway, the formula version is basically `=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,DAY(A1))` - the VBA version is simply `[A1] = DateAdd("m", 1, [A1])` It's pretty trivial, but you've posted no code so...

Comment: @QHarr I've attached a dropbox link so you can look directly at what I have now so you can better understand what I'm going for. Don't view it in browser because it will not look right. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/urncoww8prj6rc1/AccountabilityScorecardDigital.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Provided your workbook is saved, you can also use this `=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)` which will reference the current sheet name. See here: https://i.imgur.com/qoLdFIx.png

Comment: Weekly increment. That will be easy enough using date functions and converting to a string. You might want a function to parse the current worksheet names and find the max date and then add 7, or if you have missed a week, have a function that utilises the current date.

Comment: Doable but you still need to fix the rules about how the name is to be determined as per my comment above, say for example, you miss a week.

Comment: Plus, including a screenshot or markdown table insert of the data, in your question, as you shared in the dropbox will make things a lot clearer for people. It did for me.

Comment: @QHarr it won't matter if a week is missed as the page will simply be deleted by the user and current code won't recreate a deleted page. The only rules for the cell is that it needs to be auto named on a Monday - Friday dates as well as change the month/year automatically. The sheet will auto-update all relevant information based on that cell. In addition it likely just needs to rename based on the first sheet. The first sheet is the only one that isn't auto-created. I thought about creating a second sheet that has a type of addition function but it won't follow calendar year.

Comment: so when you copy the sheet you want a sub routine that dates the new activesheet cell A1 to the nearest monday past (or current day if monday), in the date format as shown?

Comment: @QHarr Close, it needs to update to the following Monday even if the date hasn't been reached yet. Think of it as a calendar, not necessarily on the date. Perhaps someone may need to add 3 weeks to it or more they can so they can use the sheet in a future date if need be. Only Monday - Friday, weekends are irrelevant.

Comment: See here for finding closest monday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116513/date-for-previous-monday-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

Just use the `GetProperWeekName` function and feed it whatever you want.

For example, `GetProperWeekName("DEC 11-15 2017", 7)`

Will Return:

`DEC 18-22 2017`

You can add days, months, or years by using the optional parameters.

To add a week, you would use `7` as I did in my example.

When you create your new sheet, just update `A1` by doing something like:

`Range("A1") = GetProperWeekName(Range("A1"),7)`

```
Function GetProperWeekName(TheWeek As Variant, Optional DaysToAdd = 0, Optional MonthsToAdd = 0, Optional YearsToAdd = 0) As String
Dim TheDate As Date
TheDate = DateValue(Trim(Left(TheWeek, WorksheetFunction.Find("-", TheWeek) - 1)))
If DaysToAdd <> 0 Then TheDate = DateAdd("d", DaysToAdd, TheDate)
If MonthsToAdd <> 0 Then TheDate = DateAdd("m", MonthsToAdd, TheDate)
If YearsToAdd <> 0 Then TheDate = DateAdd("y", YearsToAdd, TheDate)
GetProperWeekName = UCase(Format(TheDate, "mmm")) & " " & Day(TheDate) & "-" & Day(DateAdd("d", 4, TheDate)) & " " & Year(TheDate)
End Function
```

Results:

[image: Results]

**If you want it to accept normal dates and format them, it's easier:**

```
Function GetProperWeekName(TheDate As Date, Optional DaysToAdd = 0, Optional MonthsToAdd = 0, Optional YearsToAdd = 0) As String
If DaysToAdd <> 0 Then TheDate = DateAdd("d", DaysToAdd, TheDate)
If MonthsToAdd <> 0 Then TheDate = DateAdd("m", MonthsToAdd, TheDate)
If YearsToAdd <> 0 Then TheDate = DateAdd("y", YearsToAdd, TheDate)
GetProperWeekName = UCase(Format(TheDate, "mmm")) & " " & Day(TheDate) & "-" & Day(DateAdd("d", 4, TheDate)) & " " & Year(TheDate)
End Function
```

**How to update your sheet and date ranges properly:**

```
Sub UpdateSheet()
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
ActiveSheet.Name = GetProperWeekName(Range("A1"), 7)
Range("A1") = GetProperWeekName(Range("A1"), 7)
End Sub
```

[image: Resultzzz]

**QHarr's Padding Addition:**

```
Function GetProperWeekName(TheWeek As Variant, Optional DaysToAdd = 0, Optional MonthsToAdd = 0, Optional YearsToAdd = 0) As String
Dim TheDate As Date
TheDate = DateValue(Trim(Left(TheWeek, WorksheetFunction.Find("-", TheWeek) - 1)))
If DaysToAdd <> 0 Then TheDate = DateAdd("d", DaysToAdd, TheDate)
If MonthsToAdd <> 0 Then TheDate = DateAdd("m", MonthsToAdd, TheDate)
If YearsToAdd <> 0 Then TheDate = DateAdd("y", YearsToAdd, TheDate)
GetProperWeekName = UCase(Format(TheDate, "mmm")) & " " & Format(Day(TheDate), "00") & "-" & Format(Day(DateAdd("d", 4, TheDate)), "00") & " " & Year(TheDate)
End Function
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require constant feeding of the information to add? I'm trying to make it automatically function with no user input.

Comment: No user input is required - just take the current value and increment it by whatever you want. I added an example of how to update `A1`. If you want, you can tweak the function to accept normal dates and use `Now` - I set it up to use your weirdly formatted dates since you have the data right there when you copy the sheet.

Comment: What I mean to say is this, suppose I plug this into my current sheet and hit the "Next Page" button and it copies my current page. After copying it then runs this code and it returns exactly what I need it to return. That's great but then I run it again for Sheet3 and it copies Sheet2 but returns the same date because it doesn't pull the previous date from sheet2. It needs to increment with each copy.

Comment: ... have you considered passing the new date instead of the old date? Pass the copied sheet date each time instead of the original sheet date ...

Comment: Will try and post here rather than answer. UCase(Format(TheDate, "mmm")) & " " & Format(Day(TheDate), "00") & "-" & Format(Day(DateAdd("d", 4, TheDate)), "00") & " " & Year(TheDate)  to allow for the padding with 0s.

Comment: Thanks QHarr - that may be useful - I haven't played with it enough. I did post an edit on how to properly update your sheet each time with a macro.

Comment: @user1274820 Actually, that would be optimal to pass the new sheet each time however the problem still lies, I don't know how to pass that data through VBA and update using DATE conventions. If I tried to do it I'd end up with DEC 2000-2005 of 2017 lol. I just don't know how to handle dates in VBA.

Comment: @MatthewKaulfers I edited my post with code on how to update your sheets - posting example now.

Comment: @QHarr I will add your padding code - thanks bruv <3

Comment: Loving the gif - where did you go to add that?

Comment: @user1274820 +1 for your answer having a demo gif and being well thought through.

Comment: I'm about to piece this into my spreadsheet to see if I can get it functioning. I believe this is exactly what I'm looking for now.

Comment: @user1274820 Can you look at this to see what I'm missing. I'm sure it's something simple but honestly, my head hurts lol.

https://imgur.com/a/VMAgr

Comment: @user1274820 +1, I got it. Had to remove my old copy page code. It's looking good and functioning properly.